# jQuery: Scrolling accordion effect

Tags: jquery, scroll, accordion

I'm trying to reproduce an accordion effect when scrolling up and down shown on Apples website here: http://store.apple.com/us/compare/mac?mco=MTg4Mjg5Nzk&page=imac (click "Compare" on any mac then start scrolling down)

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/mackry/3KZky/15/

It's very complicated and a mess to look at. I'm obviously not taking this from the right approach and I'd like to ask if anyone else has a better way to go about composing this efficiently. It'd be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var schedule = $('#schedule'),
        schedulePos = $('#schedule').offset(),
        page = $('#page'),
        index = 0,
        prevScroll = $(document).scrollTop(),
        margin = schedulePos.top;


    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        var newScroll = $(document).scrollTop(),
            prof = $('li#professor').eq(index);

        //schedule.html($(document).scrollTop() + '  ' + $(window).scrollTop() + '<br/>Prof #1: ' + prof.offset().top + '<br/>index: ' + index);

        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= schedulePos.top && !schedule.hasClass('fix') && newScroll > prevScroll) {
            schedule.addClass('fix');

        }
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() < schedulePos.top) {
            schedule.removeClass('fix');

        }

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ((100 * (index+1)) + margin) && newScroll > prevScroll) {
            //alert(index);
            prof.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                height: '50px',
                top: (schedule.height() + (index * 50)) + 'px'
            });
            index++;
        }
        else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= ((100 * (index+1)) + margin) && newScroll < prevScroll) {
            prof.css({
                position: 'static',
                height: '150px'
            });
            index--;    
        }

        prevScroll = newScroll;
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been busy with other projects, but I finally got around to making a jQuery plugin that does this effect. [Get it from here](https://github.com/Mottie/squeezeBox) or [Check out a demo](http://mottie.github.com/squeezeBox/index.html).

Comment: Wow fudgey, great work. I finally had managed this effect, but your method looks much more efficient. Thanks mate!